# How to change the email ID of default email application Programa in android

Tags: android, email, default

It's a fairly simple question but i can not find an answer.So is it possible to change the email ID(from address) of the default email application programmatically? .WE can get the accounts associated with the device using the getAccounts() method of AccountManager class.But i need to change change the email ID of default email application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No you can not change it ,  its under Android admin device policies .

refer this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: thanks mate for the quick reply.i have gone through the above mentioned link,but where exactly or which point says that we can not change email ID of the default email app in android programmatically.

Comment: yup i get it.changing the preference of one application from another is not possible and especially something like email ID which is very sensitive.